# Filestream file change during use

Tags: c#, filestream

I'm working on a project that maintains a live backup similar to dropbox. When I use a filestream to upload my file what would happen if the file changes, is deleted, or renamed?

Comment: I guess that would fail the process... you can set FileAccess,
FileMode and FileShare using filestream  to prevent it.

Comment: well the point is to be transparent to the user so if they change a file I'm uploading I want my program to forget that task and start over with the new change @Mate

Comment: Ok, now if it sounds interesting! I'll see to test a solution ;)

Comment: I suppose part of the problem would be at what part in the stream the content was altered. I suppose you can listen for file changes and then queue up the upload again. But to allow them to save the changes when you're in "mid stream" (pardon the pun) seems problematic at best.  You could end up constantly trying to attempt to upload the file for n length of time.

Comment: @Hardrada well if the user keeps changing the file n times then sure but what I'm driving at is if filestream (or some alt) could throw an error if the file has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

Your application should have (should ensure) a file lock on that file so no changes can be made.

Comment: If my user is typing a long word doc and they save their changes then change something quickly and then resave and if I lock it then word would demand a new location, I'm trying to be invisible to the user and if they change the file that quickly then the old version is not important to me anymore. @Hardrada

Comment: I understand your parameters. What you're really trying to do accomplish is just sync'ing files. In this case, I would perhaps "listen" for file changes on a file that is "in operation" and if it's changed, cease the operation on that file and wait for it to be closed. You could peek at the file and see if it's locked. I imagine that if the file is not locked, it's not open and you can proceed to sync. For file name changes, I would just complete the op and queue up a file name sync op. As a side note, I noticed MS has a sync fwk: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb821992.aspx